# f2py bug or missing library?

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I am using `f2py` to implement some fortran 77 routines. Specifically, I want to implement the column-wise autoscale function for a 2D array.

```
      SUBROUTINE AUTOSCALE(E,NR,NC,EA,N,M,MX,SX,SSX)
      INTEGER NR,NC,N,M,I,J
      REAL*8 E(NR,NC),EA(N,M),MX(M),SX(M),SSX(M)
      DO 1 I=1,NC
          MX(I)=0D0
          SX(I)=0D0
1           SSX(I)=0D0
     DO 3 I=1,NR
        DO 2 J=1,NC
            MX(J)=MX(J)+E(I,J)
2           SX(J)=SX(J)+E(I,J)**2
3    CONTINUE
     DO 4 J=1,NC
        MX(J)=MX(J)/NR
        SX(J)=(SX(J)-NR*MX(J)**2)/(NR-1)
        SX(J)=DSQRT(SX(J))
4   CONTINUE
    DO 6 I=1,NR
       DO 5 J=1,NC
          EA(I,J)=E(I,J)-MX(J)
          EA(I,J)=EA(I,J)/SX(J)
          SSX(J)=SSX(J)+E(I,J)**2
5      CONTINUE
6   CONTINUE
    RETURN
    END
```

The routine is correctly translate to python only if I comment the line with the `DSQRT` call. If I replace it with equivalent functions, such as `SQRT`, `**(0.5)`, `**(1./2.)` I always get a strange link error. See details below.

> Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\BIN\link.exe mingw32.lib(lib32_libmingw32_a-pesect.o) : error LNK2005: **ValidateImageBase already defined in MSVCRT.lib(pesect.obj)
>   mingw32.lib(lib32_libmingw32_a-pesect.o) : error LNK2005:
>   __FindPESection already defined in MSVCRT.lib(pesect.obj) mingw32.lib(lib32_libmingw32_a-pesect.o) : error LNK2005:
>   __IsNonwritableInCurrentImage already defined in MSVCRT.lib(pesect.obj)    Creating library
>   C:\Users\PolGia0\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvzoar0ou\Release\Users\PolGia0\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvzoar0ou\src.win32-3.4\foo.lib
>   and object
>   C:\Users\PolGia0\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvzoar0ou\Release\Users\PolGia0\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvzoar0ou\src.win32-3.4\foo.exp
>   mingw32.lib(lib32_libmingw32_a-pesect.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol __image_base** referenced in function
>   __FindPESectionByName .\foo.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I don't understand it. Maybe something is wrong in the set up of my system ?
Any suggestions? Thanks
PS In case it helps, I use Anaconda 2.3.0 at 32 bit on a Windows 7 64 bit pc.

Comment: Which Fortran compiler do you use? Seems the run-time library is not linked correctly.

Comment: I use the package mingw32 coming from Anaconda distribution, that instals correctly. The modules I can compile look and perform right. Even the examples more complex (e.g. pointers to functions) are managed. I point out that Anaconda was the only distribution that gave me good results with f2py. Other installation failed to run even very trivial examples.